# How to combine rows to change the shape of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to rearrange a dataframe so that every 2 rows are combined into one row.
For example

```
0  a  b  c  d
1  e  f  g  h
2  i  j  k  l
3  m  n  o  p
```

into:

```
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
```

I need to do this for quite a large table of data and have been unable to find a solution.
I'm a complete python novice and would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the underlying numpy array and numpy's `reshape` method:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape((len(df)//2, -1)))
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
```

###### alternatively using pandas:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True),
           df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)],
           axis=1)
```

but you will have duplicated column names:

```
   0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep="\s{1,}")
df1.to_numpy().reshape(2,8)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)